seq by month in R skips months
In the code below I am trying to complete a date sequence. My start date is May 31 and end date is August 31. When I seq() by month below you will see that June 2023 is skipped but July 2023 appears twice (first and last of the month). I want to sequence by month so each month appears in the sequence between the two dates. How can I achieve this?
library(tidyverse)
df1 <- data.frame(id = "1", 
                  startdate = as.Date( "2023-05-31"),
                  enddate = as.Date("2024-08-31")) %>% 
        mutate(date_duration = startdate,
               enddate = ceiling_date(enddate, "month") -1 ) %>%
      complete(date_duration = seq(startdate, enddate, by = "month"))

Edit second example
Using the code posted by Jon below it works for my first example. However if the start date starts on the first of the month I get repeat months again. Is it possible to work around this?
df1 <- data.frame(id = c("1","2"), 
                  startdate = as.Date( c("2023-05-31", "2023-01-01")),
                  enddate = as.Date(c("2024-08-31", "2023-03-15")),
                  date_duration = as.Date( c("2023-05-31", "2023-01-01"))
                  ) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  complete(date_duration = seq(ceiling_date(startdate, "month"),
                               ceiling_date(enddate, "month"), 
                               by = "month") - 1)


I don't think that your usage of  complete()  is correct.  "Turns implicit missing values into explicit missing values. This is a wrapper around expand(), dplyr::full_join() and replace_na() that's useful for completing missing combinations of data".  I don't understand what you want to achieve:  a dataframe of 15 or 16 rows, with a start_date() on the first day of the month and a ènd_date() of the last day of the month ?

This is a shortfall of the base seq.Date function, which doesn't work as you might expect for last days of the month. (I presume this is because months have different lengths and so it's ambiguous what the user wants, and how to achieve that simply. In practice, it presumes you are looking for the date that would be where the 31st would be if it existed, so below it shows 2024-07-01 where you'd expect 2024-06-30.)
seq(ymd(20230531), ymd(20240831), by = "month")
#[1] "2024-05-31" "2024-07-01" "2024-07-31" "2024-08-31"

It works as you expect with first days of the month, though, so you might modify like this:
seq(ymd(20230531) + 1, ymd(20240831) + 1, by = "month") - 1
#[1] "2024-05-31" "2024-06-30" "2024-07-31" "2024-08-31"

You might consider something like the line below, which rounds to the next month (which will sequence as you expect), then you could go back one day. This takes care of the situation where you might provide 2024-02-28, which is not the last day of the month, but might be provided by a user expecting it to be.
I also add id, startdate, and enddate as they exist in your data. Not sure if you want that or not, but it seems useful to me.
... |>
complete(date_duration = seq(ceiling_date(startdate, "month"),
                             ceiling_date(enddate, "month"), 
                             by = "month") - 1,
         nesting(id, startdate, enddate)) # optional

Result
   date_duration id    startdate  enddate   
   <date>        <chr> <date>     <date>    
 1 2023-05-31    1     2023-05-31 2024-08-31
 2 2023-06-30    1     2023-05-31 2024-08-31
 3 2023-07-31    1     2023-05-31 2024-08-31
 4 2023-08-31    1     2023-05-31 2024-08-31
 5 2023-09-30    1     2023-05-31 2024-08-31
 6 2023-10-31    1     2023-05-31 2024-08-31
 7 2023-11-30    1     2023-05-31 2024-08-31
 8 2023-12-31    1     2023-05-31 2024-08-31
 9 2024-01-31    1     2023-05-31 2024-08-31
10 2024-02-29    1     2023-05-31 2024-08-31
11 2024-03-31    1     2023-05-31 2024-08-31
12 2024-04-30    1     2023-05-31 2024-08-31
13 2024-05-31    1     2023-05-31 2024-08-31
14 2024-06-30    1     2023-05-31 2024-08-31
15 2024-07-31    1     2023-05-31 2024-08-31
16 2024-08-31    1     2023-05-31 2024-08-31

EDIT:
Or, if we just want "one row per month", we could floor_date the defining columns first, something like: (sloppy b/c I don't know which rows you need to keep in original form)
... %>%
group_by(id) %>% 
mutate(across(contains("date"), ~floor_date(.x, "month"), .names = "{.col}_floor")) |>
complete(date_duration_floor = seq(startdate_floor, enddate_floor, "month"))


Great thank you! Ah good to know about seq.date, I updated an example where if I had two patients and the second patient starts at the first of the month it repeats months again. Is there a way to make this a bit more general

For 2023-01-01 to 2023-03-15, what sequence do you want? 3 dates or 4? Which dates?

3 dates, Jan, Feb, and March

Which three dates? Monthly starting from first month: 2023-01-01, 2023-02-01, 2023-03-01? Monthly starting from first month, but ending at end date: 2023-01-01, 2023-02-01, 2023-03-15? Monthly ending at end date: 2023-01-15, 2023-02-15, 2023-03-15?  .... etc.... ?

2023-01-01, 2023-02-01, 2023-03-01, would be more helpful! basically extracting the year and month is the most important

Edit. I'm not sure exactly how you want to implement it, but one way to do it could be to use floor_date("month") versions of your date columns, and then sequence on those.
